# In the example oauth2 server for Authlib, why is user_id tied to client meta data?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, authlib

I'm working with authlib for an oidc provider server.  I'm using [example-oauth2-server](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) as a learning tool.  I'm trying to understand why, in the database schema, the User_ID is tied to the client.  I understand this is an oauth2 server as opposed to oidc.  But the confusion still stands.  Am I meant to be registering a client for each human/service user?  This isn't a requirement in either oauth2 or oidc right?  In fact there's nothing at all in [oidc client registration docs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html) about a user_id field in relation to client metadata.

In a different oidc library I used, the registration is "user agnostic" for the lack of a better phrase.  I can't wrap my head around why it should not be.  I mean, I CAN create a client for each user, but why should I want to do so if I wanted, for example, an Android app capable of authentication and authorization via my oidc provider?  Could I not achieve something similar (assuming the purpose is to specifically identify which user is logging in,which, you can determine by the fact that said specific user is logging in) by storing the user_id in some other table?

Any direction or even discussion would be appreciated.

Comment: A client is registered by a user (developer) on your website, that is why the example has a user_id column. But it is not required.

Comment: That does make sense.  However, if that is the case, why is session based on the user_id?  This would mean if the developer-user is logged in, no password is required for authorization.  Surely that is not the intention?  btw thanks for responding.  I'm not used to asking about github issues on SO.  But you're pretty darn responsive.